# Hyperlink in Word doc to SharePoint Wiki page anchor

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word

Trying to create hyperlink within a Word doc to specific bookmark on SharePoint Wiki page. In Word, html hyperlink to wiki page works fine but when I add #AnchorName to end of hyperlink string I get page not found.  What is the right syntax?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does the bookmark work as expected on the page?

I tried to reproduce your issue but it failed. You can provide your steps (it would be better to provide some screenshots) for checking the issue.

Here are my steps:

1. Insert a link as the bookmark (section2) in the "Bookmark" page (Bookmarks.aspx).
   [image]
2. Insert a link to bookmark (#section2).
   [image]
3. Save the wiki page and test. It works.
4. Insert the hyperlink “http://sp/sites/team/SitePages/Bookmark.aspx#section2” in a Word file. By clicking this link from the file, the page is opened and it steps into the section2.